# React - Passing state to another component - Component accessed via URL

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Hi I'm very new to React (day 2). I simply want to pass a state from one component to another but I've struggled to find a tutorial that handles this in the way my project is structured (I imagine my project is structured very poorly...). I've uploaded reproducible code on codeSandbox: codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-maxwell-q83lc

#### My Code

My `App.js` currently looks like this. I access the component screens via a different url.

```
import componentOne from "./componentOne"
import componentTwo from "./componentTwo"

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Switch>

                    <Route path = "/componentOne">
                        <componentOne/>
                    </Route>

                    <Route path = "/componentTwo">
                        <componentTwo/>
                    </Route>

                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

I want to pass a state from `componentOne` to `componentTwo`. This is my `componentOne.jsx` file. By clicking an image, the url changes and hence I am at the `componentTwo` page. But I'm not sure how to pass the state from `componentOne` to it this way.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function componentOne() {
    const [stateOne, setStateOne] = useState(null)
    const [stateTwo, setStateTwo] = useState(null)
    const [stateThree, setStateThree] = useState(null)

    /**
     * API call that populates stateOne, stateTwo and stateThree
     */

    return (
        <div>
                        
            {/*I want to pass stateOne to componentTwo*/}
            <a href="/componentTwo">
                <img src = {stateOne.image} alt={""}/>
            </a>

            {/*I want to pass stateTwo to componentTwo*/}
            <a href="/componentTwo">
                <img src = {stateTwo.image} alt={""}/>
            </a>

            {/*I want to pass stateThree to componentTwo*/}
            <a href="/componentTwo">
                <img src = {stateThree.image} alt={""}/>
            </a>

        </div>
    )
}

export default componentOne
```

This is my `componentTwo.jsx` file. Note that the data I want to pass to `componentTwo` is JSON.

```
function componentTwo(props) {
    // I want my JSON data to be in props

    return(
        // I then want to use this JSON data to display things
        <text> {props.title} </text>
    )
}

export default componentTwo
```

#### What I've tried so far

So far, I've removed the `componentTwo` route path from `App.js` and added it to `componentOne` in this way, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
function componentOne() {
    return (
        <div>
        ...

           <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path = "/componentTwo">
                        <componentTwo recipe={stateThree}/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            <a href="/componentTwo">
                <img src = {stateThree.image} alt={""}/>
            </a>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to create a function for redirect, with a code like this:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/componentTwo',
  search: '',
  state: stateTwo
})
```

But in your case, you should replace your <a tags with the Link component, and then you can pass data through it:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/componentTwo',
  search: '',
  state: stateTwo
}}> ... </Link>
```

And then in the ComponentTwo you could access to the state with a code like this:

```
props.location.state.stateTwo
```

Remember to get the history and location objects from props or using the withRouter HOC.

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I click on the image, the url changes correctly to '.../componentTwo` but the page itself doesn't update. I have to manually refresh it. Is there anyway I can have this refresh automatically? Also can you clarify further on how to access the state in ComponentTwo? Currently I have a `function componentTwo(props)` .  `stateTwo` is a JSON.

Comment: As  I understand stateTwo is an object, so you should get it using props.location.state.stateTwo (I have an error in the answer, sorry).

Comment: Check if there is an error in the console, after clicking the image

Comment: In `componentTwo` I won't know if I will be working with stateOne, stateTwo or stateThree. Is there anything I can do about this? Also I checked the console and no error appears after clicking the image.

Comment: Would be great if you can set a codeSandbox, so we can help you better.

Comment: Hi sorry it took so long. Here's my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-maxwell-q83lc Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The whole point of React Router is that there isn't a page refresh. You definitely don't want that b/c it will reset your state.

Comment: So what exactly do I do? I want to display `componentTwo` only, not `componentOne` when I click an image. Based on what Image I click, I want to pass a state I created in `componentOne`.

Comment: Check this fork,  https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-ride-de4ti?file=/src/App.js 

I have made changes in the App.js router definition, and the components, there was some weird usages for Router

Comment: it works, but I strongly recommend you to find a way to store the data in some way, in order to avoid the errors on refresh the page, because on refresh the page the data will be lost.

Comment: If the data is static, you don't need to complicate it using states, just create the components with the data you want to show, and redirect to them

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much... The kindess of strangers on this forum never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) which has the [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) component that you can use to pass the state.

```js
<Link to={{pathname: "/componentTwo", state: yourstate }}>
    <img src = {stateOne.image} alt=""/>
</Link>
```

Comment: When I do that, the url is changed but the page doesn't actually navigate there. Here's my sandbox: codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-maxwell-q83lc Any help is greatly appreciated.